# New property to "export default"

Tags: vue.js, components

Is it possible or recommended to add a custom property to a component like in the below example? In that case how can I call this property from a method?

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            test = ""
        };
    },
    methods: {
        someMethod() {
            // 
        },
    },
    customLoggingData {
        title : "main",
    }
};
```

I have seen some plugins that have their own property like the `customLoggingData` and I was just curious to know if that was possible.

If not I'll just have it as a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommendation from the vuejs team is this:

```
{
  data: ...,
  created: function () {
    this.customLoggingData = {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

See this [github thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1988) for more info.